# Syntax error in property list

Tags: javascript

I have a function as below:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
        get_search_result({
            scroll_search: true;
        });
    }
});
```

And the function `get_search_result` is :

```
function get_search_results(params) {
    alert(params);
    var check_scroll_search = params.scroll_search || false;
    if (check_scroll_search) {
        alert('Scroll Search');
    }
}
```

But it does not alert anything - instead, the console is outputting this:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list  

scroll_search : true;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: any error in your borwser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have the semicolon here: `scroll_search : true;`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

http://jsfiddle.net/y4MyZ/

Comment: Also, as mentioned below http://stackoverflow.com/a/20488163/40961 `Also the function name is get_search_results, you missed the s at the end`

Answer (score 2):

you have a syntax error, remove the `;` after `scroll_search`

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
        get_search_results({
            scroll_search: true
        });
    }
});
```

Also the function name is `get_search_results`, you missed the `s` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error remove `;`

```
scroll_search: true
                // ^remove ; here
```

---

```
function get_search_result(params) {
                     //   ^ remove extra s from here
```

---

Your code becomes

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
        get_search_result({
            scroll_search: true
        });
    }
});
```

---

```
function get_search_result(params) {
    alert(params);
    var check_scroll_search = params.scroll_search || false;
    if (check_scroll_search) {
        alert('Scroll Search');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of ";" there

```
get_search_result({
        scroll_search: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` after `scroll_search: true;`

it should be like

```
scroll_search: true
```

Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('body').height() * 0.7)) {
        get_search_result({
            scroll_search: true
        });
    }
});
```